# How to find a file that has different column type during import (and then don't import it)?

Tags: r

I have a million csv files with the same column headers but somewhere a non.double value has appeared in a file. They all import into a list which I then unlist ok. But when I need to manipulate these columns or perform some operation on them I hit an error which says they can't be converted to type double. How can I find out where which file has the problematic non-numeric entry?

```
list_of_files<-list.files(pattern="*.csv")

selectCols = c("pax.id","origin","destination","mask.wearing","prevalence","location.time.series","Dose.air","Dose.close","Dose.fomite")
selectCols = which(names(temp) %in% selectCols)

df<- rbindlist(sapply(list_of_files, fread, select = selectCols, simplify = FALSE),
                use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")
```

**EDIT:**

Based on Ronak Shah's answer below:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))))) %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns = is.na))) %>%
  distinct(FileName)
```

This produces and empty tibble.

Reproducible example:

**EXAMPLE FILE with entries:**

```
dput(OKFILE)
structure(list(pax_id = 0, origin = "A", destination = "F", mask_wearing = structure(1L, .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), prevalence = 0.00025, dose_air = 0.000952123039018727, 
    dose_fomite = 6.61087941578422e-11, simulation = "ID1", dose_close = 0, 
    location_time_series1 = "2+", location_time_series2 = "2+", 
    location_time_series3 = "2+", location_time_series4 = "2+", 
    location_time_series5 = "2+", location_time_series6 = "none", 
    location_time_series7 = "none", location_time_series8 = "none", 
    location_time_series9 = "none"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fcfb00110e0>)
```

**EXAMPLE FILE with a non-numeric row:**

```
dput(OffendingFile)
structure(list(pax.id = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    origin = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    destination = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    time.boarding = structure(1L, .Label = "[hh:mm:ss]", class = "factor"), 
    time.alighting = structure(1L, .Label = "[hh:mm:ss]", class = "factor"), 
    is.infectious = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    mask.wearing = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    seed = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), prevalence = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    source.strength = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus s-1]", class = "factor"), 
    close.range.strength = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus s-1]", class = "factor"), 
    boarding.surfaces.touched = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    alighting.surfaces.touched = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    initial.hand.concentration = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus m-2]", class = "factor"), 
    final.hand.concentration = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus m-2]", class = "factor"), 
    location.time.series = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor"), 
    time.in.range.0.1.m = structure(1L, .Label = "[s]", class = "factor"), 
    time.in.range.1.2.m = structure(1L, .Label = "[s]", class = "factor"), 
    Dose.air = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus]", class = "factor"), 
    Dose.close = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus]", class = "factor"), 
    Dose.fomite = structure(1L, .Label = "[virus]", class = "factor"), 
    Probability.of.Infection = structure(1L, .Label = "[-]", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Do you need to find only the filename or even column name that has non-numeric entry? Are all of `selectCols` supposed to be numeric? What are you going to do after you find out the filename (and/or column name) of non-numeric entry?

Comment: Not all of those columns are double (e.g. origin, destination and location.time.series aren't). So I guess I need to know that if I try to convert all the other columns to numeric, which file's column won't convert. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one way of getting the names of the file that won't convert.

```
library(dplyr)

#Include all the columns that we want to check for being numeric
selectCols = c("origin","destination","mask.wearing","prevalence","Dose.air","Dose.close","Dose.fomite")
#Read them into one dataframe
df <- bind_rows(sapply(list_of_files, data.table::fread, 
               select = selectCols, simplify = FALSE), .id = "FileName")
```

Once we have the data in one dataframe we turn all the values to numeric and select the rows that don't turn to numeric. We select only the unique filenames from it.

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))))) %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns = is.na))) %>%
  distinct(FileName)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The result is an empty tibble though

Comment: @HCAI Can you make a reproducible example for us to work on? Create multiple small dataframes combine them with your code `df<- rbindlist(sapply(list_of_files, fread, ....`. Update your post with `dput(df)` so that we have some data and show expected output for it.

Comment: I'm sorry Ronak, there are too many steps to make a reproducible example. I will vote to close the question. I found that the reason things didn't work in my original code was because a file had 1 row of non-numeric values that wasn't being caught initially. I fixed that and the code works ok, but I'm still a bit puzzled why your example returns an empty tibble.